# Set key programmatically with string variable

Tags: r, data.table

Because `setkey` does some magic with `subsitute`

```
#>setkey
function (x, ..., verbose = getOption("datatable.verbose"), physical = TRUE) 
{
    if (is.character(x)) 
        stop("x may no longer be the character name of the data.table. The possibility was undocumented and has been removed.")
    cols = as.character(substitute(list(...))[-1])
    if (!length(cols)) 
        cols = colnames(x)
    else if (identical(cols, "NULL")) 
        cols = NULL
    setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical)
}
```

I cannot pass a string variable as colname to `setkey` without it being treated as an expression:

```
data = data.table(mtcars)
key = 'qsec'
setkey(data, key)
# Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) : 
# some columns are not in the data.table: key
setkey(data, 'qsec')
# Works as expected
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Use `setkeyv`..?

Comment: Thanks you, that worked (how stupid of me)